# Angular - How to resolve Class is using Angular features but is not decorated. Please add an explicit Angular Decorator

Tags: angular

In my Angular-15 project, I have this component.ts

```
import {Component, HostBinding, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Store} from '@ngrx/store';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

const BASE_CLASSES = 'main-sidebar sidebar-dark-danger elevation-4'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-sidebar',
  templateUrl: './admin-sidebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-sidebar.component.scss']
})
export class AdminSidebarComponent implements OnInit {
  userName = localStorage.getItem('username');
  userRole = localStorage.getItem('role');
  @HostBinding('class') classes: string = BASE_CLASSES;

 public menu = [
  {
    name: 'Transfer Auths',
    iconClasses: 'fas fa-users',
    path: ['/admin-dashboard/transfer-auth-list']
  },
  {
    name: 'Transfers List',
    iconClasses: 'fas fa-edit',
    path: ['/admin-dashboard/transfers-list']
  }
 ];

  constructor(
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {

  }
  getUserName() {
    return this.userName;
  }
}
```

Then I got this error:

```
Class is using Angular features but is not decorated. Please add an explicit Angular Decorator.
```

Then **AdminSidebarComponent** is highlighted in:

```
export class AdminSidebarComponent implements OnInit {
```

In order to solve the problem, I disable the extension:  "Angular Language Service". Yet the issue is not resolved.

How do I get this sorted out.

Comment: It looks odd. As you have used `@Component()` which is the decorator. Does this issue happen to this component only, or do others have the same issue? Have you tried to re-build and start the app?

Comment: @YongShun - I re-build and started it. Then it works fine. What could have cause that, because I didn't do anything on it.

Comment: Sometimes you need to restart the typescript server or, if you're using some VS code extension. This usually happens if you switch branches or make other changes while angular is being served.